# javascript/mootools | Custom events

Tags: javascript, events, object, mootools

**I have 1-st script:**

```
<script>
   App.validate(helper, form, "", // Simple request to the server
      function(data) {
         if (data.products_in_cart) {
           ... I dont't know how to trigger event (cart update for example)  
         }
      },'POST'
   );
</script>
```

**And 2-nd (as a plugin):**

```
<script>
   var handler = document.id('html');
   handler.addEvent('event from the script above - cart update', function(data){
     handler.set('html', JSON.stringify(data));
   });
</script>
```

Is this possible to create?
My javascript framework is Mootools.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script>
   App.validate(helper, form, "", // Simple request to the server
      function(data) {
         if (data.products_in_cart) {
           window.fireEvent('validateEvent', {cart:data});
         }
      },'POST'
   );
</script>
```

and the other file:

```
<script>
   var handler = document.id('html');
   handler.addEvent('validateEvent', function(data){
     handler.set('html', JSON.stringify(data));
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Should be: window.fireEvent('validateEvent', {cart:data});